# Script tag in shopify using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, shopify-app

How to implement script tags in shopify using my laravel app (php). I want to show some dynamic text in product page. so how to include my app content using script tags??

Comment: Please provide some code that you've implemented to better explain the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer- You can refer this link to add script tags in the shopify store using your php app [laravel package](https://github.com/ohmybrew/laravel-shopify)

Answer (score 1):

You can add script tag using bellow code

```
POST /admin/script_tags.json

{
    "script_tag": {
        "event": "onload",
        "src": "https:\/\/djavaskripped.org\/fancy.js"
    }
}
```

also you need shopify domain and token to create this request. You can add your dynamic code in the js file like first you have to check that current page is product page and then if yes then show your dynamic text there.

Thanks

Comment: I have added the bellow code in my controller 
            $src = "http://localhost/shopifyplugin/shopify.js";
            $script = $shopify->call('POST', '/admin/script_tags.json', array(
            "script_tag"=> array(
                "event"=>"onload", "src"=>"$src"
             )));  

But it is showing error = array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: Can you check that your script tags is registered or not by using below code?
 '''GET /admin/script_tags.json'''

Comment: $brandurl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
    $script = array(
            "script_tag"=> array(
              "event"=> "onload",
              "src"=> $brandurl,
              "display_scope"=>"all"
            )
          );
    $scriptAdd = $sc->call('POST','/admin/script_tags.json',$script);

Comment: Still Showing ErrorException (E_WARNING)
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

I have also used GET/admin/script_tags.json, but also getting an error